# Why does Concurrent-Mark-Sweep (CMS) remark phase need to re-examine the thread-stacks instead of just looking at the mutator's write-queues?

Tags: jvm, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot, vm-implementation

The standard CMS algorithm starts by making the application undergo a STW pause to calculate the GC-root-set. It then resumes mutator threads and both application and collector threads run concurrently until the marking is done. Any pointer store updated by a mutator-thread is protected by a write-barrier that will add that pointer reference to a write-queue.

When the marking phase is done we then proceed to the Remarking phase: it must then look into this write-queue and proceed to mark anything it finds there that was not already marked.

All of this makes sense. What I fail to understand is why would we need to:

1. Have this remarking phase recalculate the GC-root-set from scratch (including all thread stacks) -- does not doing this result in an incorrect algorithm, in the sense of it marking actually live and reachable objects as garbage to be reclaimed?;
2. Have this remarking phase be another STW event (maybe this is because of having to analyse all the thread-stacks?)

When reading one of the original papers on CMS [A Generational Mostly-concurrent Garbage Collector](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.3953&rep=rep1&type=pdf) one can see:

> The original mostly-concurrent algorithm, proposed by
>   Boehm et al. [5], is a concurrent “tricolor” collector [9]. It
>   uses a write barrier to cause updates of fields of heap objects
>   to shade the containing object gray. Its main innovation is
>   that it trades off complete concurrency for better throughput, by allowing root locations (globals, stacks, registers),
>   which are usually updated more frequently than heap locations, to be written without using a barrier to maintain
>   the tricolor invariant.

it makes it look like this is just a trade-off emanating from a conscious decision to not involve what's happening on the stack in the write-barriers?

Thanks

Comment: not a bad question, at all. Just bear in mind that `CMS` is deprecated and no one supports it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Have this remarking phase recalculate the GC-root-set from scratch (including all thread stacks) -- does not doing this result in an incorrect algorithm, in the sense of it marking actually live and reachable objects as garbage to be reclaimed?

No, tricolor marking marks live objects (objects unmarked by then "grey" set is exhausted are unreachable). Remark add rediscovered root objects to "grey" set together with all reference caught by write-barrier, so more objects could be marked as live.

In summary, after CMS remark all live objects are marked, though some dead objects could be marked too.

> 2. Have this remarking phase be another STW event (maybe this is because of having to analyse all the thread-stacks?)

Yes, remark is STW pause in CMS algorithm in HotSpot JVM (you can read more about CMS phases [here](https://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots_02.html)).

And answering question from title

> Why does Concurrent-Mark-Sweep (CMS) remark phase need to re-examine the thread-stacks instead of just looking at the mutator's write-queues?

CMS does not use "mutator's write-queues", it does utilize card marking write barrier (shared with [young generation copy collector](https://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html)).

Generally all algorithms using write barriers need STW pause to avoid "turtle and arrow" paradox.

CMS starts initial tri-color marking. Then it completed "some" live objects are marked, but due to concurrent modifications marking could miss certain objects. Though write-barrier captures all mutations, thus "pre clean" add all mutated references to "gray" set and resume marking reaching missed objects. Though for this process to converge, final remark with mutator stopped is required.

Comment: Now I got it. Thx.